# Echo script arguments from function

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts

I need to get script arguments within function with arguments.

```
./myscript 1 2 3

function_name () {
   if [ $1 == 3 ]; then
        # I need the $1 in the following echo to be the script argument, not the function argument
        echo $1 $2 $3
   fi
}

function_name $#
```

Comment: Is the function defiend inside the script? If so, you can store the argumants to a global array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite interesting. The problem is the scope of the function is overriding that of the script. I can't see a simple way around that.

However, you can just pass the variables along as arguments (into the function):

```
function_name () {
   [[ $# == 3 ]] && echo $1 $2 $3
}

function_name $@
```

Or you could:

- Pass `$# $@`, check `$1`, and `echo $2 $3 $4`
- Pass `$# $@`, check `$1`, `shift` and then `echo $1 $2 $3`
- Store `$@` as a script-level variable and access it from within the function

Comment: Could not up the answer due to lack of points.

Comment: In the end I used a case statement. Passing in $#. With this doing the 'if' outside of the function, I was able to pass through, the 3 Args I needed from the Script to the Function.. function_name $2 $3 $4.